# Which is the Issue Register NOT used for?

Tags: prince2

I am going to give the Prince2 exam soon. And in there, it says

Which is the Issue Register NOT used for?

And the answer is "Capture any threats or opportunities that might have an impact on a stage"

I thought that is what issue register does.. It records issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PRICE2 differentiates between "issues" and "risks". An issue is something that is happening or has happened in the past. A risk is something that may occur and impact a project. Threats or opportunities that might impact a stage would be considered risks, and not issues, and would therefore be tracked on your Risk Register.